# How to fix Flutter package flutter_video_cast breaking iOS simulator build on Apple Silicon Mac (M1 or M2)

Tags: flutter, build, package, arm64, apple-silicon

**My issue:**

Adding [`flutter_video_cast`](https://github.com/kkoken/flutter_video_cast/tree/master/ios) package to my project stops it building for arm64 on Apple Silicon Mac.

```
Error (Xcode): In /<path>/ios/Pods/google-cast-sdk-no-bluetooth/GoogleCastSDK-ios-4.6.1_static/GoogleCast.framework/GoogleCast(aligned_new_bca0ac320467a2457b3e306bfed17856.o), building for iOS Simulator, 
but linking in object file built for iOS, 
file '/<path>/ios/Pods/google-cast-sdk-no-bluetooth/GoogleCastSDK-ios-4.6.1_static/GoogleCast.framework/GoogleCast' 
for architecture arm64
```

- **Please note**: if I exclude arm64 from the iOS simulator build in Xcode project, it DOES build, but then scrolling / inertia is broken.
- I have **no** option to open the simulator with Rosetta either, when I check the 'Get info' properties.

**So things I’ve tried:**

- Forking the plugin and adding arm64 to the podspec file in VALID_ARCHS
- Removing VALID_ARCHS from the the podspec file
- Setting  podfile in Flutter config:

```
config.build_settings['VALID_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'x86_64 arm64'
config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "i386"
```

None of the above works.

**Q)** So has anyone managed to get their project building for iOS simulator when a particular package doesn’t specify arm64 in its podspec file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the newest xCode versions the option to open it with Rosetta is no longer available.

I had a very similar issue with xCode 14.3 on macOS 13.3.1.

The solution for me was this - Go to the "Product" menu in the menu bar and select Destination > Destination Architectures > Show Rosetta Destinations.
Then you will see Rosetta in parenthesis next to the simulator name. Run it. That's all.

Hope this helps.
Here is the original source of this information - [Link](https://sarunw.com/posts/open-using-rosetta-in-xcode-14-3/)